# How do I use a function and class from another file in "pytest"?

Tags: python, pytest

I need to be able to instantiate a `Store()` object but at the moment it isn't defined in my test.

I've tried using imports but it'll say that a module isn't defined.

```
flaskr/
  __init__.py
tests/
  store_test.py
```

There's a class in the `__init__.py` file.

```
class Store():
  name = ""
  postcode = ""
  latitiude = ""
  longitude = ""
```

Want to use it in the test in `store_test.py`:

```
def test_store_creation():
  store = Store()
  store.name, store.postcode = "Brighton", "BN1 8FH"
  assert store.name == "Brighton"
  assert store.postcode == "BN1 8FH"
```

Just need to be able to use the `Store()` class here, there's a way round it but don't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it out, and the directory structure you need is the following:

```
someFolder
|
|-- flaskr
|   `-- ___init__.py
|
`-- store_test.py
```

And then you can import the Store class: `from flaskr import Store`

Comment: Store() is also within a function called `create_app` so how would I import it from that?

Currently I'm getting an ImportError

Comment: Why is the class within that function? Is there any need for it to be there? Could provide the code for how the `create_app` is written?

Comment: When the class is part of a definition, it becomes local, so I don't think you can import it somewhere else then, depending on how your definition is written.